# multi-line pattern matching in python

Tags: python, regex, multiline

A periodic computer generated message (simplified):

```
Hello user123,

- (604)7080900
- 152
- minutes

Regards
```

Using python, how can I extract "(604)7080900", "152", "minutes" (i.e. any text following a leading `"- "` pattern) between the two empty lines (empty line is the `\n\n` after "Hello user123" and the `\n\n` before "Regards"). Even better if the result string list are stored in an array. Thanks!

edit: the number of lines between two blank lines are not fixed.

2nd edit:

e.g.

```
hello

- x1
- x2
- x3

- x4

- x6
morning
- x7

world
```

x1 x2 x3 are good, as all lines are surrounded by 2 empty lines, x4 is also good for the same reason. x6 is not good because no blank line follows it, x7 is not good as no blank in  front of it. x2 is good (not like x6, x7) because the line ahead is a good line and the line following it is also good.

this conditions might be not clear when I posted the question:

```
a continuous of good lines between 2 empty lines

good line must have leading "- "
good line must follow an empty line or follow another good line
good line must be followed by an empty line or followed by another good line
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to go over these lines (assuming you have a list of lines, or a file, or split the string into a list of lines) until you see a line that's just `'\n'`, then check that each line starts with `'- '` (using the `startswith` string method) and slicing it off, storing the result, until you find another empty line. For example:

```
# if you have a single string, split it into lines.
L = s.splitlines()
# if you (now) have a list of lines, grab an iterator so we can continue
# iteration where it left off.
it = iter(L)
# Alternatively, if you have a file, just use that directly.
it = open(....)

# Find the first empty line:
for line in it:
    # Treat lines of just whitespace as empty lines too. If you don't want
    # that, do 'if line == ""'.
    if not line.strip():
        break
# Now starts data.
for line in it:
    if not line.rstrip():
        # End of data.
        break
    if line.startswith('- '):
        data.append(line[:2].rstrip())
    else:
        # misformed data?
        raise ValueError, "misformed line %r" % (line,)
```

Edited: Since you elaborate on what you want to do, here's an updated version of the loops. It no longer loops twice, but instead collects data until it encounters a 'bad' line, and either saves or discards the collected lines when it encounters a block separator. It doesn't need an explicit iterator, because it doesn't restart iteration, so you can just pass it a list (or any iterable) of lines:

```
def getblocks(L):
    # The list of good blocks (as lists of lines.) You can also make this
    # a flat list if you prefer.
    data = []
    # The list of good lines encountered in the current block
    # (but the block may still become bad.)
    block = []
    # Whether the current block is bad.
    bad = 1
    for line in L:
        # Not in a 'good' block, and encountering the block separator.
        if bad and not line.rstrip():
            bad = 0
            block = []
            continue
        # In a 'good' block and encountering the block separator.
        if not bad and not line.rstrip():
            # Save 'good' data. Or, if you want a flat list of lines,
            # use 'extend' instead of 'append' (also below.)
            data.append(block)
            block = []
            continue
        if not bad and line.startswith('- '):
            # A good line in a 'good' (not 'bad' yet) block; save the line,
            # minus
            # '- ' prefix and trailing whitespace.
            block.append(line[2:].rstrip())
            continue
        else:
            # A 'bad' line, invalidating the current block.
            bad = 1
    # Don't forget to handle the last block, if it's good
    # (and if you want to handle the last block.)
    if not bad and block:
        data.append(block)
    return data
```

And here it is in action:

```
>>> L = """hello
...
... - x1
... - x2
... - x3
...
... - x4
...
... - x6
... morning
... - x7
...
... world""".splitlines()
>>> print getblocks(L)
[['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['x4']]
```

Comment: @Thomas Wouters, "for line" is not reliable (otherwise I won't tag this question with multiline ;-) I can only start the matching _after_ "\n\n- " (two linefeeds then a leading minus-sign and space)

Comment: That wasn't (and still isn't) in your question, but the basic approach remains the same. You can still use iteration over lines just fine, but you'll have to clarify what you actually have and actually want if you want me to write down an example. What if there's lines that don't start with "- " inbetween lines that do? What if there's multiple such blocks? What if the lines aren't empty but just have some whitespace?

Comment: I'm still not sure how my current answer doesn't work for you. (I don't see a second edit?)

Comment: updated, "a continuous of good lines between 2 empty lines" section, thx

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> x="""Hello user123,
...
... - (604)7080900
... - 152
... - minutes
...
... Regards
... """
>>>
>>> re.findall("\n+\n-\s*(.*)\n-\s*(.*)\n-\s*(minutes)\s*\n\n+",x)
[('(604)7080900', '152', 'minutes')]
>>>
```

Comment: @S.Mark, sorry that I didn't make the question clear, please see the edit about undefined number of rows between the two blank lines.

Comment: @Horace, added \n+ to match more than 2 blank lines

Comment: @S.Mark, is it possible to take away (minutes) from the re? as "minutes" does not necessary show up at last row

Comment: @Horace, Yeah, you could change `(minutes)` to `.*` if you don't want in the result.

Comment: Throwing a complicated one liner like `re.findall("\n+\n-\s*(.*)\n-\s*(.*)\n-\s*(minutes)\s*\n\n+",x)` and providing no explanation in your answer is an **extremely bad practice**.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = """Hello user123,

- (604)7080900
- 152
- minutes

Regards
"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'^- (.*)', s, re.M)
['(604)7080900', '152', 'minutes']
```

Comment: You should add at least one line of explanation in your code of how `re.findall(r'^- (.*)', s, re.M)` works

Answer (score 1):

```
l = """Hello user123,

- (604)7080900
- 152
- minutes

Regards  

Hello user124,

- (604)8576576
- 345
- minutes
- seconds
- bla

Regards"""
```

do this:

```
result = []
for data in s.split('Regards'): 
    result.append([v.strip() for v in data.split('-')[1:]])
del result[-1] # remove empty list at end
```

and have this:

```
>>> result
[['(604)7080900', '152', 'minutes'],
['(604)8576576', '345', 'minutes', 'seconds', 'bla']]
```